# What is the best way to correct a user's reversing of an edit?

Tags: discussion

[Here are the revisions of the relevant question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/135626/revisions).

The `game-design` doesn't apply to this question. But just putting in another edit isn't going to help the user know that the tag isn't right and why. I feel like it would muddy the comments section of the question to explain that there.

What's the best approach to educate and fix the question's tags?

Comment: It seems to me that game-design needs a bit of a work for clarification since people seem to be misusing it too much (about 25% of questions closed or on-hold in the first page) not sure how I'd go about that though. Maybe put the relevant tags in the guideline instead of the expanded explanation? This would make those a click or just a hover distance instead of two clicks.

Comment: I had a similar [issue this past week with a user who objected to / rolled back most edits to their question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142041/why-are-my-network-players-only-able-to-shoot-horizontally-in-my-first-person-sh). Ultimately I just let it be, figuring voting would take care of it if other users found the question unclear as it was phrased at the time. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short "hey, I am editing your question because of X Y" is certainly appropriate for the comments section. In this case, the question is clearly about programming, in general. I have made a brief comment pointing to the usage guidelines of the [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design), where it specifically says "not for programming questions about 'design' of features".

Once you feel the point has been made, and assuming it is your comment, there is no need to flag for moderators attention. It is your comment, and as such, you are free to remove it at any time. In this case, it certainly helps to have the [editing privledge](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), which is awarded at 2,000 reputation. Without it, edits are pushed to a review; and in this case, the edit was flat out rejected by the asker.

In this case, I have applied the [programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag, as I feel the question does not specifically apply to [graphics-programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-programming), but is certainly against the usage guidelines of [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design). It is possible that the asker may still insist on the original edit, and roll it back. If you are confident that such an edit was appropriate, you should flag the question for moderator attention, as opposed to entering a "rollback war".

Answer (score 2):

Commenting on the question is what I'd recommend. The comments can be removed when they are no longer relevant or if the discussion escalates to the point where a specific meta post should be made.

If the user insists on tagging a question incorrectly after discussion, flag the post for moderator attention and we'll deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the comments section for that; once the message got through (or it did not get through), and you had a discussion with the user, you can flag the messages for a moderator's attention and explain that the comments are no longer needed.

I'm not sure where, but I've seen on meta.se that it was not worth doing an edit war with the user. If they're not willing to receive help to have their question get the best visibility, their loss.

Comment: Well I'm also concerned with the fact that the `game-design` tag gets misused so much that when I come to look at questions for that tag, most of them aren't related. So individual question visibility is important, but also keeping the tag useful for someone looking to provide answers.

Comment: @Chris I know how you feel about de-cluttering the tag; then I'd suggest to follow the suggestion Josh made and flag the question for moderator attention if it goes on.

Comment: Yes; generally, you shouldn't engage in a rollback war with a user over things like formatting the question, how they phrase it, et cetera. If they want that to remain unadulterated, even if it hurts their question's answerability, it's generally fine. But mis-using a tag is not.